# How tracking new subscribers in Google Analytics?

Tags: asp.net

I waana tracking new subscribers in google analytics but how.

the site enables sign up in two places :

1-in POp up

2-in page that also user can login in

Any one have an idea how do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could simply look at the url you display after a successful subscription.

However, if you'd like to see the number of an action over time, independently of the url, you could use *Event tracking*. GA allows to track user defined events, all you need to do is to execute a little bit of javascript - in your case after a subscription occurs.

Google has an [extensive guide on how to set up event tracking](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/eventTrackerGuide.html).

Comment: i think i have one solution by using javascript cause i have not page after a successful subscription ( i redirect new subscriber to the ReturnURl) so i have many pages. Do u have any another idea?!